# How do I get the number of rows of a related table returned using JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm working on creating a forum system that contains forums, threads, posts and likes. This question is about the latter two tables, which were created with these statements:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
    postID INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    postDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    postContent TEXT NOT NULL,
    postThread INT(8) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(postThread) REFERENCES threads(threadID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON 
        UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE likes
(
  likeID INT(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  likeUserID INT(8) NOT NULL,
  likePostID INT(8) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(likePostID) REFERENCES posts(postID),
  FOREIGN KEY(likeUserID) REFERENCES users(userID)
);
```

On each thread page (`thread.php?id=x`) I query the database to get the following data that will be echoed in my HTML:

```
SELECT posts.postID, posts.postContent, likes.likePostID           
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.postID = likes.likePostID
WHERE posts.postThread = ?
ORDER BY posts.postDate asc
```

In phpmyadmin I get the following result when I run this statement:

```
postID | likePostID | postContent
   1         3            foo
   1         3            foo
   1         3            foo
   2        NULL          bar
   3        NULL          blah
```

I want to know how to get the number of rows returned by `LEFT JOIN` in which the current post's ID matches a `likePostID` where the `likePostID` is not null, which in the above example is 3 for the post with an ID of 1. This value will be echoed for each post on the page near the "like" button. Can this be done using one query, or will I need to find the number of likes per post separately?

I'm currently echoing all relevant information using `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: For what it's worth, I solved this by doing additional `INSERT` statements in my `like.handler.php` script. I asked this question because I wanted to know about the method presented in this question.

Answer (score 0):

SQL has a count function as described here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

```
select count(column_name) from table where condition
```

obviously you would have to bulk outt that query with your joins, but that would give you a count.

Otherwise there is a function in php mysqli_num_rows() which will return the row count.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer. However, using COUNT with my query will only return the posts on each page that contain likes (since likePostID and postID must be present). Unfortunately, I was hoping to be able to find the value I need using only my provided query.